# VBA/Excel - Add/embed dropdown (combobox e.g.) inside ChartObject

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Is it possible to add a dropdown list, for example a ComboBox, inside a ChartObject (the chart it self), so that it also moves with the chart, if said chart is moved?

I've found [this source](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/how_to_create_an_interactive_chart_with_drop-down_list_in_excel.html) that appears to have done it (top images), but they are not explaining how the dropdown list is added inside the chart.

I know you can add it on top of the chart, by simpling placing it there, but the list is required to be added **inside** the chart, enabling one to move it around.

**Edit:** trying to group the combobox and chart doesn't seem to work as hoped to. At least when I try to move the chart, the combobox doesn't follow. This is the same if I try to add an "Option control" and group it.

Comment: Er, [Group Them](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-or-ungroup-shapes-pictures-or-other-objects-a7374c35-20fe-4e0a-9637-7de7d844724b)?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that @SiddharthRout, but grouping a combobox with the chart doesn't seem to work as I hoped it would. At least when I try moving the chart, the combobox doesn't follow. I will add that to the original question.

Comment: It does. But you need to move it in a specific way else it will not move :)

Comment: **1.** Group the Form Control Drop Down and the chart. **2.** Right click on the Form Control Drop Down. The Chart borders will get activated.  **3.** Drag using those borders. **Note:** When you directly try to move the chart, it is not the chart which moves. It is the chart area.

Comment: @SiddharthRout ooh, I see! Damn.. Good to know, although when I can't see the logic at first, i'm afraid that other users might miss it as well. You don't know any other way to embed the combobox?

Comment: No I am not aware but you can put the chart inside a shape and use it like [THIS](https://prnt.sc/onujp7) :D

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rd2u2cq7a6xgeu/ChartMoveExample.xlsx?dl=0) is a demo sample.

Comment: @SiddharthRout very good idea, although has some of the downsides as grouping. Maybe add this as an answer and I will accept as the best answer, if a "true" embed solution cant be found :)

Comment: That's ok. You can post it as an answer and accept it if a "true" embed solution cant be found :)